# DomEvent.InitEvent throws an exception (GeckoFx 45.0.19)

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, geckofx

I want to click on a div element. Because the div element does not support `.click()` so I tried `dispatchEvent` method.

My code is show below:

```
Dim ev_mouse_down As nsAStringBase = DirectCast(New nsAString("mousedown"), nsAStringBase)
Dim ev_mouse_up As nsAStringBase = DirectCast(New nsAString("mouseup"), nsAStringBase)
Dim ev_mouse = wbGec.Document.CreateEvent("MouseEvent")

ev_mouse.DomEvent.InitEvent(ev_mouse_down, False, False)
div_ele.GetEventTarget.DispatchEvent(ev_mouse)
```

Note:
- `wbGec` is my `GeckoWebBrowser`.
- `div_ele` is the div element I want to simulate a mouse click on it.

But when I debug, it throws an exception:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.AccessViolationException'
>   occurred in Automation.exe
>       Additional information: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.

The error cause by this line:

```
ev_mouse.DomEvent.InitEvent(ev_mouse_down, False, False)
```

Does anyone explain me how to use the `dispatchEvent` in `GeckoFx`?!
Additional info: I am using GeckoFx 45.0.19 NuGet package, .NET Framework 4.

Comment: Please report an issue in the Geckofx 45 bug tracker: https://bitbucket.org/geckofx/geckofx-45.0/issues

Comment: I reported this on issue #92.